# React - pass state to Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple React+Hooks webapp, I have a route1 that renders componentA.
On ComponentA, I can render the proper jsx for that component or redirect to Route2, if a condition is meet.
On the route2, I need to get some of the states from componentA that route1 renders.

ComponentA.jsx

```
return (
        <Fragment>
            {!call ? 
                (
                    <div className="container">
                        //some jsx
                    </div>
                )
                : 
                (
                    <Redirect to={{pathname: '/route2', state: { meeting, name }}}/>
                )}
        </Fragment>
);
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {

    return(
        <AuthProvider>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/route1" component={ComponentA} />
                    <Route exact path="/route2" component={ComponentB} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
};
```

I was trying to get the state `props.location.state` on ComponentB.jsx, but it's always undefined. Is there a way to pass those parameters to a route or do I need to use Context to solve that?

Comment: You might've made a typo for meeting and name. You put a , instead of ;

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, however `props.location.state` will be undefined unless you specifically set it via programmatic navigation. If you reload the page for instance, or navigate via URL, or navigate without setting it, it will not be there. You have to account for that in the component, and you should avoid putting any data in there that needs to be available regardless of how the route is reached. You'll usually be better off storing any shared state in a shared parent, in this case `App`.

Here's a working example. It uses `BrowserRouter` as I cannot get the npm `history` package with `createBrowserHistory` to load properly in a snippet, but it's essentially the same as creating history that way and feeding it to your regular `Router`:

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } = window.ReactRouterDOM;

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/route1" component={ComponentA} />
        <Route exact path="/route2" component={ComponentB} />
        <Redirect to="/route1" />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

function ComponentA() {
  const [redirect, set] = useState(false);
  const string = "state preserved";

  return redirect ? (
    <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/route2", state: { string } }} />
  ) : (
    <button onClick={() => set(true)}>Redirect with state</button>
  );
}

function ComponentB(props) {
  return (
    <div>{props.location.state ? props.location.state.string : "no state"}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.0.1/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```